# How to display all text label values in custom label in tabel view?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I am new to iphone development. I am using a tableView which loads a UITableViewCell with a UIlabel inside it. In cellForRowAtIndexPath, i want to store all the cell textLabel value in a custom UILabel. There is only one table view cell row. Our UILabel frame is same as table cell frame as i have mention in my code. From mutable array, i am getting different indexPath row cell text label value.

Here is my code..

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    Cuisine *cuisine = [[Cuisine alloc] init];// Cuisine is my object entity class..

    //Custom UILabel

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 3, 310, 30)];
    label.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:57/255 green:57/255 blue:57/255 alpha:1.0];
    label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:14];

    NSLog(@"array is = %@", array);
    label.text = [[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] cuisineName];// here i am getting  
    first cuisine name string value for 0 indexPath row.

    [cell addSubview:label];

   }
 return finalCell;
}
```

Using this code, i am getting first cuisine name string value for indexPath row 0. So how can i display all string value for all arrays in UILabel text ?

Output should be like..

name1,name2,name3,name4,nam.....

Thanks in advance..

Comment: If you only have one row, why are you using a table view?

Comment: @rdelmarso instead of table view, can i use only UILabel.

Comment: But i need to set delegate also on cell.

Comment: Sure,why not. You can use stringWithFormat or stringByAppendingString to build up a string that contains all the strings in your array.

Comment: Why do you need to set a delegate?

Comment: her i have tried using this code.. label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@, %@, %@, %@, %@, %@",[[arraySelectedCusines objectAtIndex:0] cuisineName], [[arraySelectedCusines objectAtIndex:1] cuisineName],[[arraySelectedCusines objectAtIndex:2] cuisineName],[[arraySelectedCusines objectAtIndex:3] cuisineName],[[arraySelectedCusines objectAtIndex:4] cuisineName],[[arraySelectedCusines objectAtIndex:5] cuisineName],[[arraySelectedCusines objectAtIndex:6] cuisineName]];

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37378/discussion-between-rdelmar-and-anand-gautam)

Comment: if user will tap on cell, it will navigate to next view controller class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make a single String of All Array Values like this,Just make a single global string and whereever you populating this array do this with that global string and access anywhere

```
NSString *str = @"";

for(int i=0;i<array.count;i++)
{
    NSString *cuisineName = [[array objectAtIndex:i] cuisineName]; 
    str = [str stringByAppendingFormat:@",%@",cuisineName];

}
```

and now show this string in your label Simple.